# PostgreSQL "syntax error at end of input" after INSERT INTO with GraphQL and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql

Using `pg-promise` to insert a user into the database like so:

```
const { db } = require('../../utils/pgAdaptor');
const query = 'INSERT INTO "Users" (email, password, "createdAt", "updatedAt") VALUES';
    const values = [email, password, new Date(), new Date()];
    console.log(values) // [ 'test', 'test', '2019-03-01T05:08:34.523Z', '2019-03-01T05:08:34.523Z' ]
    return db
      .none(query, values)
      .then(res => res)
      .catch(err => err);
```

I can insert a row myself using pgAdmin

```
INSERT INTO "Users" (email, password, "createdAt", "updatedAt") VALUES ('test', 'test', '2019-03-01T05:08:34.523Z', '2019-03-01T05:08:34.523Z');
```

I've tried using `db.one` and I've tried a couple of the examples from [PostgreSQL Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html) but I get the error `"message": "syntax error at end of input"` from the `GraphiQL` interface either way. What am I missing here? What is wrong with the input exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add placeholders such as `$1`, `$2`, … into your query so that the PostgreSQL driver nows where and how to insert the values you provide. See [the documentation of the `pg` module](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query) for more details.

This could then look like this:

```
INSERT INTO "Users" (email, password, "createdAt", "updatedAt") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
```

The way you wrote it you actually try to run

```
INSERT INTO "Users" (email, password, "createdAt", "updatedAt") VALUES
```

which, as the error message states, is a syntax error.

Besides that: What is this `.none()` method? I have never seen it, and the documentation for the `pg` module doesn't mention it either. From my point of view this should be `.query()`.

Comment: From the [methods](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#methods) sections of the pg page here, "All query methods of the library are based off generic method query." So you're right, `query()` would work too. `.none()` just means no rows are returned, `.one()` is one row returned, etc.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for the explanation! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL make statements using ? as the parameter, And PostgreSQL uses $1, $2 etc.

Now your current query is

```
const query = `INSERT INTO "Users" 
              (email, password, "createdAt", "updatedAt") 
              VALUES`;
```

You need to convert your query into this format

```
const query = `INSERT INTO "Users" 
               (email, password, "createdAt", "updatedAt")
               VALUES 
               ($1, $2, $3, $4)`;
```

Now in your query become

```
db.Query(`INSERT INTO "Users" 
          (email, password, "createdAt", "updatedAt")
          VALUES 
          ($1, $2, $3, $4)`, 
          ['test', 'test', '2019-03-01T05:08:34.523Z','2019-03-01T05:08:34.523Z'])
```

You can use string instead of the template string. Just for clearification syntax.